# Is it alright to leave a PS2 on all night?

Tags: ps2

I have a PS2, but I don't have a memory card. I've had to leave the PS2 on all night for like four nights.

Is it alright to leave it on for that long? I've done research but I'd like to hear it from you guys.

Comment: What research?  What did you find?  Just saying, "I've done research" does absolutely nothing to help us help you.

Comment: people say that it will over heat

Comment: @user69492 What kind of dimensions is your PS2 in?

Comment: @Frank: I up voted his question. Research or no, this is still a clear question that will be useful to future readers.

Comment: define 'alright'. Is it completely harmless? no.  Will it break tomorrow because of it? no

Comment: thank you all for your comments you have all been very helpfull

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About five years ago I was playing Spyro on PS1 and I accidentally forgot to turn it off before leaving for more than two weeks on a trip. When I got back, I found it still working, and I even finished some more levels without any problems.

I don't even turn off my PC at all now, since I'm using it all the time.

All modern tech, assuming you're not leaving it under blazing summer sun or in some other obviously horrible conditions, is going to be fine. Just be aware that it'll keep adding to your electricity bill.

Answer (score 11):

Applies the same principle with all machines, they get hot and this can in the long run harm your system and reduce the its life span. It's better just to turn it off or at least in a suspend state to allow preserve the system.

Comment: will it be ok??

Comment: They were designed to be ran running 24/7 would only reduce the lifespan but it would have the same number of operational hours

Answer (score 4):

The answer varies between system to system, and the setup of that console. The age of the console is probably another factor you'll want to account for, as components like the fan will probably become damaged/weaker over time.

For example, I own a: Wii, xBox 360 and a xBox One. Sometimes, I would neglect to turn the Wii off, but it was okay, as it was well ventilated. I used to keep my 360 on all night, to allow to download large games; I can't do that anymore, as it's now in a cramped space. With my One, it has a low power feature, so I leave it in that when ever I'm out the house, as any updates are automagically installed, and it's well ventilated.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it before and it will be OK as long as it's well ventilated you will be able to leave you're console on for a very long time.

All i can say is, make sure your wires are well maintained and have no damage as these could cause sparks if faulty and that's the last thing you would want to happens while you're asleep.

Comment: -1: It is extremely unlikely that leaving a console on will burn someone's house down.

Comment: @Kevin Did I say it was likely? I said it's OK to leave the console on. Notice the word **but** in my answer? that kind of gives it away.

Comment: You're right. If you so desire, edit your question and I'll give you your vote back.

Comment: @kevin edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, everyone. Left mine on for a month due to a near-death experience. once I had recovered enough to go home, it was still running. Started it up the next day, and it was just fine. My PS2, sadly, died a few years ago. Then again, it was around 10 years old.