# Can you shoot while driving?

Tags: watch-dogs

I was playing around on my buddie's copy of the game, and every time I got in a car chase I died because I thought I was playing GTA. I asked him and he didn't know, though he is notorious for ignoring all tutorial text. I was able to get a targeting reticle up, which gave me hope, but no cigar for me. Is this a game mechanic, or did they leave it out for one reason or another?

Comment: He's holding his phone in the hand he's not driving with...

Comment: You can't shoot as others have said, but since just about everything around you is hackable, it's even better. You can unlock different hacking abilities in the upgrade menu that allow you to blow manhole covers and activate road spikes. It's pretty easy to take down a car once you get the timing down.

Comment: Second Amendment rights notwithstanding, most states don't allow you to use a phone while driving, let alone … oh wait, this is Arqade, isn't it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not shoot whilst driving in Watch underscore Dogs.

Comment: I literally lol'd when I read that. Now I'm going to pronounce the game like that...

Answer (score 5):

No you can't, according to these sources:

[vg24/7 Review](http://www.vg247.com/2014/05/27/watch-dogs-review-ama-ask-me-anything/)

> Q) From T-Dawg6: How is driving in the game? I heard its a bit stiff.
>   Also can you shoot while driving? & can you fly airplanes/helicopters?
>
> A) You heard correct T-Dawg. Some of the cars are really sticky on the
>   road, so you won’t be pulling off Ridge Racer-grade drifts or anything
>   like that. I would have liked it to have been a little slicker, but
>   you get used to it over time. **You can’t shoot while driving either**,
>   and I suspect that’s to make you use hacks while driving to give cops
>   the slip instead.

There is also a discussion at [GameFAQS](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704529-watch-dogs/69312576)

Answer (score 4):

No, as far as I know, you can not shoot while driving. In a tutorial text in the beginning of the game, it is explained that the advantage of a co-driver is that they can shoot, while the driver can not. You will also notice that enemies won't shoot either, unless they have a co-driver.

Answer (score -5):

You can shoot while driving, its farther in the game once you hit 53.6% you automatically can drive and shoot, its more of a game mod/cheat. 
Also i heard that if you beat all driving tasks to 100% it will let you shoot out of car.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like your answer is incorrect. We're downvoting it not to be mean, but so that future readers know what's correct and what isn't. Having answers downvoted is part of how Arquade works, so everyone makes some mistakes – I myself have had answers downvoted because they were wrong, like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163795/is-it-alright-to-leave-a-ps2-on-all-night/163874#163874). If you have other game knowledge you'd like to share, I hope you stay active at Arquade!